# How to update a value of a cell of a dataframe using the value of two cells below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe (created for an example):

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6
```

Assuming that this is a long dataframe, whenever there is a value of 2 in row B, I need to replace that value with the value that is two cells below that.

I tried:

```
for val in df['B']:
    if val == 2:
        df['B'] = df.B.shift(-2)
```

But I get:

```
    A   B
0   1   6.0
1   1   NaN
2   4   NaN
```

And I need:

```
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  1  6
1  1  3
2  4  6
```

Does anyone have suggestions for leaving rows that do not equal '2' unchanged?

Comment: mask the locations where `B` is 2: `df['B'] = df.B.mask(df.B.eq(2), df.B.shift(-2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then we just need to assign it with `shift`

```
df.loc[df['B'].eq(2),'B'] = df.B.shift(-2)
df
Out[458]: 
   A    B
0  1  6.0
1  1  3.0
2  4  6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].where(df['B'] != 2, df['B'].shift(-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the dataframe, which is somehow not optimized at all but works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 2 and ix < len(df)-2:
        row['B'] = df.iloc[ix+2]['B']
```

There are probably better/more elegant ways to do this.